# How to query a model and its related model in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am building a Laravel 5.5 project where i have 2 related models, User and Service with a relationship like so:
Inside User.php

```
public function service()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
}
```

and inside Service.php

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I need to query the service model for a service column where the query is either service_name or the name of a user. In effect, the query will search for the item in the service model and the related user model.
I have written the query below but its returning an empty collection:

```
$items = Service::where('service_name', 'LIKE', "%".$query."%")
                 ->whereHas('user', function($q) use ($query){
                  $q->where('name', 'LIKE', "%".$query."%");))->get();
```

What am i doing wrong?

NB: My search on google, stackoverflow and laravel documentation didn't give exactly what i need hence my question please.

Comment: Did you tried ? orWhere instead of whereHas ?

Comment: are you sure that service_name and user.name will share same variable? In your where clause you are using same variable name $query

Comment: @Mr Gandhi $query is the item (query) variable been searched for. Thanks.

Comment: @ViperTecPro orWhere didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your  "whereHas()" to "OrWhereHas()".